# Query with 2 right joins and group by doesn't display correct results

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

Can anybody help me with this query ?

I have 3 tables :   orders, customers and products.

I need to have a list of the number of orders for each customer + for each product.
Like this:

```
Customer A    Product X     4
Customer A    Product Y     0
Customer A    Product Z     0
Customer B    Product X     2
Customer B    Product Y     0
Customer B    Product Z     1
Customer C    Product X     0
Customer C    Product Y     0
Customer C    Product Z     8
```

I tried a query like this :

```
SELECT c.Name, p.Name, COUNT(o.OrderID)
FROM orders AS o
RIGHT JOIN customers AS c ON c.CustomerID=o.CustomerID
RIGHT JOIN products AS p ON p.ProductID=o.ProductID
GROUP BY c.Name, p.Name
```

but I can't get it to work !
It only displays the combinations where the counter>0  (where there are records in 'orders').  But with only 1 join it DOES work, and then it DOES correctly display the records with a counter of 0.  (In this example there are no products Y sold, but I do want to see Y in the list of combinations)

Any ideas?

Comment: Thanx all for the suggestions. I ended up with a complex query with 3 sub-queries (separate SELECT's used as a join), where I make a pivot-table for each combination (cross join) that I left join with a 'totals'-select.  Otherwise it was almost impossible to get the right totals AND also keep the records where the total is NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a cross join.  This is Oracle SQL, so not sure if it'll work for mysql.

```
select c.Name, p.Name, count(o.orderid)
from customers c cross join products p
left join orders o on c.customerid=o.CustomerID and p.ProductID=o.ProductID
GROUP BY c.Name, p.Name
order by c.name, p.name
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use outer joins and have the customers be the left side of the query, then the orders to be the left side of the remaining query, because it's the customers then orders you want to group by.

I prefer left outer joins because they map better to what you actually mean:

```
SELECT c.Name, p.Name, COUNT(o.OrderID)
FROM customers c
  left outer join orders o ON c.CustomerID=o.CustomerID
  left outer join products p ON p.ProductID=o.ProductID
GROUP BY c.Name, p.Name
```

Comment: This will not work because if you do not have orders you will not have also products on a customer.

Comment: That's fine though, the rows will have nulls which is what he wants. If you only care about customers who HAVE orders, change the first `left outer join` to an `inner join`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select c.Name, p.Name, sum(case when o.ProductId is not null then 1 else 0 end)
from customers c,products p
left join orders o on c.CustomerID=o.CustomerID and p.ProductID=o.ProductID
GROUP BY c.Name, p.Name
```

If it still does not work you can do like this, which should be an equivalent

```
select c.Name, p.Name, sum(case when o.ProductId is not null then 1 else 0 end)
from customers c
join products p on 1=1
left join orders o on c.CustomerID=o.CustomerID and p.ProductID=o.ProductID
GROUP BY c.Name, p.Name
```

(I am guessing here .. as I said I have no sql at hand)

Comment: When I try this, I get a 'Unknown column 'c.CustomerID' in ON clause' error.  I noticed this behaviour when trying to join on a double (2 tables) FROM

Comment: I do not know what to say .. I have no MySql at hand .. try to take out the table aliases.

Comment: I think it works now!  With a simple COUNT instead of the complex SUM it works too, it seems. Is there a special reason you use that SUM ?

Comment: yes .. because if you use count it will count you the line even if there is no order (will be 1 line). So if there is no order I put it to count as 0.